# authentication to github via jenkins error

Tags: git, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins on to a Windows 10 machine and receive the following error when attempting to authenticate to github using Username and password credentials within the Source Code Management section:

```
Failed to connect to repository : ....
returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed ....
```

I am able to clone the repo to C: through the terminal with no issue and I have also managed to perform the same setup using the same credentials on macOS with no issue. The windows machine I am using is however being accessed remotely via a VPN

I have tried to configure using SSH key pairs but receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF) 
  at AzureDevOps.Authentication.TokenScope.op_BitwiseOr(TokenScope left, TokenScope right) 
  at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program..cctor() 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
  at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed .....
```

any help here would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the repo I was attempting to access had two factor authentiocation the solution here was to use a Personal Access Token generated in github instead of the password when accessing over HTTPS.